# How to find total of a column value in a dynamic table in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a view with dynamic table.
When loading the page there can be existing rows. Also user can add new rows and can save the same. In the table there are two columns net_amt and quantity.
at the bottom of the table I need to show the total of these column is it possible. Please share some idea regarding the same.

**Dynamic template of table**

```
<table id="Newservice" style="display:none">
<tr>
<td><input class="" style="width:40px" type="text" name="provider_service_dtls[#].net_amt" value /></td>
<td>
<input class="" style="width:25px" type="text" name="provider_service_dtls[#].quantity" value />
<input type="hidden" name="provider_service_dtls.Index" value="%" />
</td>
<td><input id="delete" class="delete" value="X" type="button"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Table inside the view**

```
@if (Model != null)

    {
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.provider_service_dtls.Count; i++)
    {
    <td>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.provider_service_dtls[i].net_amt, new { style = "width: 40px;"})
    <td>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.provider_service_dtls[i].quantity, new { style = "width: 25px;" })
    <input type="hidden" name="provider_service_dtls.Index" value="@i" />
    </td>
     <td><input id="delete" class="delete" value="X" type="button"></td>
    </tr>
     }
    }
    </table>
```

**Table View in Browser**
[image]

When open a request there will be zero rows or more. When adding rows and after filling the values in the text box the total should change automatically. I think its only possible by jquery but im totally stucked here. please help

Comment: @downvoter pls tell why this is downvoted..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need javascript/jquery to handle the `.change()` event of your textboxes. Since you can dynamically add new rows to to table, you will also need to use event delegation using `.on()`.  The following example is based on your table having `id="myTable"` and it includes a second `tbody` element with a row `id="totals"`

Html

```
<table id="myTable">
  <tbody>
    .... // you for loop for generating existing rows
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="totals">
      <td>##</td> // insert existing total
      <td>##</td> // insert existing total
      <td></td> // blank (delete button column
  </tbody>
```

Script

```
var body= $('#myTable').children('tbody').first();
var totals = $('#totals');
body.on('change', 'input[type="text"]', function() {
  var total = 0;
  var columnIndex = $(this).closest('td').index();
  var rows = body.find('tr');
  $.each(rows, function() {
      var amount = $(this).children('td').eq(columnIndex).children('input[type="text"]').val();    
      total += new Number(amount);
  });
  totals.children('td').eq(columnIndex).text(total);
});
```

[Refer this fiddle for working example](http://jsfiddle.net/8ex94gkg/1/)

Comment: @StephenMuecek thanks for the reply..i will check and let u know..but in your fiddle if i change the default value from 0 to anyother number let be 10 it is not reflecting to the total when page load..for that what i should do

Comment: Not sure what you mean - assuming you have calculated the existing totals on the server as assigned it to `ViewBag` properties then in your footer it would be `<td>@ViewBag.Column1Total</td>` to display the initial totals. The script will then recalculate the totals whenever you change any textbox.

Comment: Also, strongly suggest you do use inline styles, especially when using a template to dynamically add new items - just too hard to maintain if you make changes. Instead use css to style your table - [see this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ex94gkg/2/) for some examples

Comment: thanks for the update..let me change my code and design..will update u the outcome

Comment: do i need to change the template for dynamic row addition also according to the table..in template i have only the fields inside the for loop. if i modified the existing table according to the above code the new row addition is not happening.

Comment: if i remove `<tbody>
    <tr id="totals">
      <td>##</td> // insert existing total
      <td>##</td> // insert existing total
      <td></td> // blank (delete button column
  </tbody>` new row addition is working @StephenMuecke

Comment: if i change any value for existing rows it is reflecting in the total but i am not able to add new rows to the table..

Comment: your code is working according to my requriement but im facing two problems..1. Not able to add new rows dynamically. 2. Totals are not calcualted when a row is deleted using the delete button. is it possible to give an idea hw to solve these two. sorry for disturbing

Comment: From your previous questions, that because you are probably using `table.append(newrow);` But because you now have 2 `<tbody>` elements  inside the table it would need to be `body.append(newrow);` where `body` is `var body = $('#myTable').children('tbody').first();` as per my code above.

Comment: For the 'Delete' action, you just need a similar function to recalculate the totals. Hard to give you the exact solution without see your code for deleting rows, so best if you ask a new question showing that code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82388/discussion-between-sachu-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 1):

Try out this little quantity adding function:

```js
function recalculate() {
  $('tr').each(function() {
    $(this).find('button').parent().remove();
    $(this).append("<td><button type='button'>" + ($(this).find('input:first').val() * $(this).find('input:last').val()) + "</button></td>");
  });
}

$('input').change(function() {
  recalculate()
});

recalculate();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="number" value="1" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" value="2" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="number" value="3" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" value="4" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="number" value="5" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" value="6" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: my problem solved with below answer it was the apt one..upvoted for your effort..thanks