# how multiply value of two columns and show in another column in a dynamic row of MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

have a view with dynamic table. When loading the page there can be existing rows. Also user can add new rows and can save the same. In the table there are two columns net_amt and quantity. at the bottom of the table I need to show the total of these column is it possible. Please share some idea regarding the same.

Dynamic template of table

```
<table id="Newservice" style="display:none">
<tr>
<td><input class="" style="width:40px" type="text" name="provider_service_dtls[#].net_amt" value /></td>
<td>
<input class="" style="width:25px" type="text" name="provider_service_dtls[#].quantity" value />
<input type="hidden" name="provider_service_dtls.Index" value="%" />
</td>
<td><input id="delete" class="delete" value="X" type="button"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Table inside the view

```
  @if (Model != null)

        {
        for (int i = 0; i < Model.provider_service_dtls.Count; i++)
        {
        <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.provider_service_dtls[i].net_amt, new { style = "width: 40px;"})
        <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.provider_service_dtls[i].quantity, new { style = "width: 25px;" })
        <input type="hidden" name="provider_service_dtls.Index" value="@i" />
        </td>
         <td><input id="delete" class="delete" value="X" type="button"></td>
        </tr>
         }
        }
        </table>
```

Table view
[image: tableview]

Now i need to multiply `netamt` and `qty` and need to show it in a read only column next to it. For an existing row the value will retrieve from model but the data should change when the value in `netamt` or `qty` got changed. pls help me to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the change event of the textboxes, get the value of both textboxes in the corresponding row, and update the rows total, for example if the html for a row is

```
<tr>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
  <td><input type="text"></td>
  <td></td> // cell for the row total
  <td><button type="button">X</button></td>
</tr>
```

Then the script would be

```
table.on('change', 'input[type="text"]', function() {
  var cells = $(this).closest('tr').children('td');
  var value1 = cells.eq(0).find('input').val();
  var value2 = cells.eq(1).find('input').val();
  cells.eq(2).text(new Number(value1) * new Number(value2));
});
```

Refer [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ex94gkg/6/) which is an update to your 
[previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31198120/how-to-find-total-of-a-column-value-in-a-dynamic-table-in-mvc/31199206#31199206),